# Error while checking a list

Tags: python

I was trying to check if 9 exists in a list but I keep getting this error:
"list index out of range"
My code:

```
def array_front9(nums):
    for i in range(3):
     if nums[i]==9:
       return True
       break
     else:
       return False
```

"nums" is supposed to be a list only. Αlso Ι am new to python and programming in general. Αny help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's the content of ``nums``? looks as if it has less than 3 items.

Comment: `nums` probably has < 3 elements.  The real questions is why not use `9 in nums`?

Comment: @MikeScotty this seems to be the issue, lemme try to fix that

Comment: @PatrickHaugh tried that way now error "can't assign to literal"

Comment: Just to check: add `print(nums)` as the first line of the function and see if `nums` is really a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not know how long the list 'nums' will be, rather say:

```
def array_front9(nums):
    for num in nums:
        if num==9: return True
        else: return False
```

**Edit**: Or rather as @Patrick Haugh and @chrisz suggested:

```
def array_front9(nums): return 9 in nums
```

Comment: `return 9 in nums`